# Is It Possible to Include Markups Within If Then Else Statements?

Tags: plugins, php

I'm trying to add an else statement to an if statement that has a foreach loop. When I added the else statement it just renders a blank page with no error. It used to work before the else statement.

Here's my code:

```
<?php if ( $locations ) { ?>
  <?php foreach ( $locations as $index => $location ) { ?>
    <div class="location-item" data-index="<?php echo $index; ?>">
      <input type="text" name="guide-locations-<?php echo $index; ?>-name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $location['name']; ?>">
      <?php
      $editor_content = $location['description'];
      $editor_id = 'guide-locations-' . $index . '-description';
      $settings = array(
        'textarea-name' => 'guide-locations-' . $index . '-description',
        'media-buttons' => true,
        'textarea-rows' => 5,
        'tinymce' => array(
          'toolbar1' => 'formatselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | blockquote | link unlink | | pastetext removeformat | code',
          'toolbar2' => '',
          'toolbar3' => '',
          'toolbar4' => '',
        ),
      );
      wp-editor( $editor_content, $editor_id, $settings );
      ?>
      <input type="text" name="guide-locations-<?php echo $index; ?>-map" placeholder="Google Maps Embed Code" value="<?php echo $location['map']; ?>">
      <a href="https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?hl=en"><span class="dashicons dashicons-info"></span></a>
      <label> Wi-Fi Available</label> <input type="checkbox" name="guide-locations-<?php echo $index; ?>-wifi" <?php checked( $location['wifi'], true ); ?>>
      <input type="text" name="guide-locations-<?php echo $index; ?>-price" placeholder="Price" value="<?php echo $location['price']; ?>">
      <input type="text" name="guide-locations-<?php echo $index; ?>-hours" placeholder="Store Hours" value="<?php echo $location['hours']; ?>">
      <button class="location-delete-button button" data-index="<?php echo $index; ?>">Delete</button>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="location-item" data-index="0">
      <input type="text" name="guide-locations-0-name" placeholder="Name" value="0">
      <?php
      $editor_content = '';
      $editor_id = 'guide-locations-0-description';
      $settings = array(
        'textarea-name' => 'guide-locations-0-description',
        'media-buttons' => true,
        'textarea-rows' => 5,
        'tinymce' => array(
          'toolbar1' => 'formatselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | blockquote | link unlink | | pastetext removeformat | code',
          'toolbar2' => '',
          'toolbar3' => '',
          'toolbar4' => '',
        ),
      );
      wp-editor( $editor_content, $editor_id, $settings );
      ?>
      <input type="text" name="guide-locations-0-map" placeholder="Google Maps Embed Code" value="0">
      <a href="https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?hl=en"><span class="dashicons dashicons-info"></span></a>
      <label> Wi-Fi Available</label> <input type="checkbox" name="guide-locations-0-wifi">
      <input type="text" name="guide-locations-0-price" placeholder="Price" value="0">
      <input type="text" name="guide-locations-0-hours" placeholder="Store Hours" value="0">
      <button class="location-delete-button button" data-index="0">Delete</button>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```